# Can we run ANSYS Fluent/OpenFOAM simulations in AWS or any free server?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, cfd, ansys-workbench

I was planning to run some FSI related simulations. But the computation capacity that I have is not sufficient. But I had heard that there is a possibility to create instances in the Amazon EC2 or the Lambda and use it for computations. But it is not very straight forward. But I wanted to know if it is even possible at all to run such high computations on the Amazon server.

If anyone knows a way to use a free server for some software like fluent or OpenFOAM then please do mention the previously asked question or share the way to use the services.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run simulations on AWS compute nodes.  Lambdas are probably not the right choice though.  You will need the right licenses for commercial software and have to make sure you can store the software somewhere instead of installing them every time you want to run a simulation.  AWS is not free, but you can run a few test cases on free nodes for a short period of time.  There's a steep learning curve.

Comment: I am afraid of that steep learning curve. The AWS module is so confusing to the beginner user with all the terminology that most people just leave.